# Apache Nutch 1.16 Fetcher reducers?

Tags: mapreduce, web-crawler, nutch

As per Apache Nutch 1.16 Fetcher class implementation here - https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/branch-1.16/src/java/org/apache/nutch/fetcher/Fetcher.java, this is a map only job.
I don't see any reducer set in the Job.  So my question is why not set job.setNumreduceTasks(0) and save the time by outputting directly to HDFS.

Answer (score 0):

So after discussing in Nutch's user mailing list, I have concluded that even though there is no reducer class associated with Fetcher.java, its still needed because the output needs to be sorted by keys i.e URL's in this case.
So if we set setNumreduceTasks = 0, No sort phase will happen and mapper will write directly to HDFS and you will notice "key out of order exception" exception in your logs.

Code details - Check this line - https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/branch-1.16/src/java/org/apache/nutch/fetcher/Fetcher.java#L490, its using FetcherOutputFormat.java as output format and if you look at this class here https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/branch-1.16/src/java/org/apache/nutch/fetcher/FetcherOutputFormat.java#L77, it uses hadoop MapFile, which adds entries In-order and hence Sort phase can't be skipped.

Also, please note that outside of crawling flow, there are other tools like SegmentReader (https://nutch.apache.org/apidocs/apidocs-1.16/org/apache/nutch/segment/SegmentReader.html) which expects data to be sorted as well.